# discord.js - How to get user Display Name from User Profile of user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

displayName will return the nickname if set in the guild (server), or the username If there is no nickname in the guild (server).

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    execute(client, msg, args) {
        msg.reply(`Hello ${msg.member.displayName}`)
    }
}
```

How can i get nickname of user from User Profile? not guild (server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get global display name with this code:

```js
msg.reply(`Hello ${msg.member.user.globalName}`)
```

the `msg.member.user.globalName` will get Display Name of user from User Profile (Account Settings)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are referring to the global display name (The Display Name set in Account Settings), which can be accessed like this:

```
msg.reply(`Hello ${msg.author.displayName}`)
```

See:
[Message.author](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Message?scrollTo=author)

[User.displayName](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/User?scrollTo=displayName)

[User object](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#user-object-user-structure) (Discord's documentation about users, this explains which field is what a bit better)

Comment: When i try, That give me undefined